# Is it possible to combine Visualforce and lightning component together?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an App (Desktop) which is already build using visualforce page in it. Now, as Lightning components available i want to use it.

Could you please make me clear on following points:

1. My app is integration app (do to many API call) and most of the places Visualforce pages are used. So is it good choise to move on Lightning Component?
2. I heart that, still Lightning Components does not have complete functionality that Visualforce have. So to use functionality that support Visualforce and not Lightning Component, Is it possible to combine visualforce and lightning component together and complete the App?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With lightning out feature in developer preview ,its certainly possible to combine lightning components with the visualforce.

The steps are highlighted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

You can build independent lightning components and use small script with lightning out defined to achieve deep integration between visualforce and lightning components.

To precisely answer your question

1)There is nothing stopping you to have integration done via lightning component .Also since it will asynchronous callouts via lightning components you can do as many callouts as you need .(There will be 3MB size limit for each callout and max poll time of 120 seconds for each callout)

2)There are specific things that are little difficult in lightning than in visualforce like navigation between different components .But you can still combine both lightning and visualforce both ways .

One advantage of building your page in lightning component will be re-usability.

You can use in App builder pages ,New lightning experience pages ,Salesforce 1 ,If you need functionality for communities you can use that as well .

If your App is typical Single page application you can convert to lightning component or create multiple components and drop into visualforce .

Recently there are lot of blogposts on how to do this and if that helps please find below

[Peters blog](http://peterknolle.com/lightning-components-in-visualforce/)

[Bob's blog](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2015/10/lds-activity-timeline-lightning.html)

[Winter 16 release session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi_5gZc5EFE)

[My own attempt to get values from component into javascript](http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2015/11/using-lighting-out-with-visualforce.html)

Comment: Lightning Components for Visualforce is not in dev preview - it is a fully GA'ed product. Using Lighting Out (the tech that powers LC4VF) outside of Visualforce is the feature that is in Dev Preview.